# Cannot Use Another Class in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, global-variables

I have this problem where I can't use another class inside the same package. Here is the code:

```
package Main;
public class App {
    public App() {
        new GUI();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

And here is the command that I use to run the application:

```
cd "c:\Save_File_Program\Java\FinalProject\src\Main\" ; if ($?) { javac App.java } ; if ($?) { java App }
App.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        new GUI();
            ^
  symbol:   class GUI
  location: class App
1 error
```

[image: My java project that I can't run]

I do have GUI.java inside Main package, same as App.java.
This problem occured after I tried to connect mysql with java using JDBC.

The steps that I followed is:
download mysql-connector-java.jar, copy the jar to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_331\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar", and make a new system variable named "CLASSPATH" with a value to the jar path.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need to import this class in this fila App.java

Comment: Somewhere you are making a basic mistake, but it isn't obvious from your (partial) description what it is.  Show us the source code for `GUI`.  Did you compile `GUI.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that your code references a class from a different file, that javac does not know about. It should work if you call `javac` with all required files. In your case either `javac *.java` or `javac App.java GUI.java Menu.java`.